# How can I implement the template using the Django model below?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I just started programming using Django and making a dental chart interface but having troubles making the template. I guess my challenge started with how I designed my previous models. A dental chart is composed of 32 teeth, each tooth has its own attributes. Below is my model:

```
class DentalChart(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField()
dentist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
PERIODONTAL_CHOICES = (
    ('Gingivitis', 'Gingivitis'),
    ('Early Periodontitis', 'Early Periodontitis'),
    ('Moderate Periodontitis', 'Moderate Periodontitis'),
    ('Advanced Periodontitis', 'Advanced Periodontitis'),
    ('N/A', 'N/A')
)
periodontal_screening = MultiSelectField(choices=PERIODONTAL_CHOICES, default='')
OCCLUSION_CHOICES = (
    ('Class(Molar)', 'Class(Molar)'),
    ('Overjet', 'Overjet'),
    ('Overbite', 'Overbite'),
    ('Midline Deviation', 'Midline Deviation'),
    ('Crossbite', 'Crossbite'),
    ('N/A', 'N/A')
)
occlusion = MultiSelectField(choices=OCCLUSION_CHOICES, default='')
APPLIANCES_CHOICES = (
    ('Orthodontic', 'Orthodontic'),
    ('Stayplate', 'Stayplate'),
    ('Others', 'Others'),
    ('N/A', 'N/A')
)
appliances = MultiSelectField(choices=APPLIANCES_CHOICES, default='')
TMD_CHOICES = (
    ('Clenching', 'Clenching'),
    ('Clicking', 'Clicking'),
    ('Trismus', 'Trismus'),
    ('Muscle Spasm', 'Muscle Spasm'),
    ('N/A', 'N/A')
)
TMD = MultiSelectField(choices=TMD_CHOICES, default='')

class Tooth(models.Model):
chart = models.ForeignKey(DentalChart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tooth_id = models.CharField(max_length=2)
CONDITIONS_LIST = (
    ('', ''),
    ('Present Teeth', 'P'),
    ('Decayed', 'D'),
    ('Missing due to Carries', 'M'),
    ('Missing (Other Causes)', 'Mo'),
    ('Impacted Tooth', 'Im'),
    ('Supernumerary Tooth', 'Sp'),
    ('Root Fragment', 'Rf'),
    ('Unerupted', 'Un')
)
condition = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CONDITIONS_LIST, default='')
RESTORATIONS_LIST = (
    ('', ''),
    ('Amalgam Filling', 'A'),
    ('Composite Filling', 'Co'),
    ('Jacket Crown', 'Jc'),
    ('Abutment', 'Ab'),
    ('Pontic', 'Po'),
    ('Inlay', 'In'),
    ('Implant', 'Imp'),
    ('Sealants', 'S'),
    ('Removable Denture', 'Rm')
)
restoration = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=RESTORATIONS_LIST, default='')
```

I created this UI using standard HTML form so that I can visualize how it would look like. But I haven't figured out how to incorporate Django so that it would be easier to refer to the tables once I create functions such as adding and editing dental charts.

[Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/narNN.jpg)

I am having a hard time to show the dental chart on my template. I hope to get some answers and tips from the experts. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What do you mean with "doesnt look near to what I want it to be"?

Comment: I deleted the phrase you are referring to as I realized that it is too vague.